# How to group by and get distinct rows of of grouped rows based on certain criteria

Tags: r

I have the following data and the first row is the header. Spaces are not important. I want to find out distinct combinations of `ATP Group` and `Business Event` that have the Category `EQ` and those that do not have the category `EQ`. In the example below, the combinations `02/A` and `02/B` have `EQ` and the combination `ZM/A` does not.

If I have a larger file, how to get to this answer? Thanks in advance.

What did I try (with `dplyr`)

I know that the below is not correct and not giving desired results

```
file1_1 <- file1  %>% group_by(ATP.Group,Business.Event) %>% filter(Category != "EQ") %>% distinct(ATP.Group,Business.Event)
```

for some reason, I have to convert to data.frame to print the data correctly

```
file1_1 <- as.data.frame(file1_1)
file1_1
```

Data shown below

```
|ATP Group|Business Event|Category|
|02       |A             |AC      |
|02       |A             |AD      |
|02       |A             |EQ      |
|ZM       |A             |AU      |
|ZM       |A             |AV      |
|ZM       |A             |AW      |
|02       |B             |AC      |
|02       |B             |AY      |
|02       |B             |EQ      |
```

Answer (score 0):

I have grown to be a fan of dplyr and so that is my hammer for everything. I made a small modification to the code. Shown below

> > code start
> >     file1 <- read.table("scope of check jul13 v2.txt", header = TRUE, sep = "|", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, strip.white = TRUE)

file1 <- select(file1, ATP.Group,Business.Event,Category)

file1_1 <- file1  %>% group_by(ATP.Group,Business.Event) %>% filter(Category == "EQ") %>% distinct(ATP.Group,Business.Event)
file1_1 <- as.data.frame(file1_1)
file1_1

file1_2 <- file1  %>% group_by(ATP.Group,Business.Event) %>% distinct(ATP.Group,Business.Event)
file1_2 <- as.data.frame(file1_2)
file1_2

setdiff(select(file1_2,ATP.Group,Business.Event), select(file1_1,ATP.Group,Business.Event))

> > code end

This works with the data that I have. If there are more elegant ways of doing this, please let me know. Thanks,

Satish Vadlamani